# link users pace static library to KMDF Windows

Tags: hyperlink, kmdf, grpc-c++

I have defined Hello() function in a C++ library(VS C++ project, static library configuration). I have created KMDF project. I want to link this driver to the function "Hello()" defined in the library. I keep getting unresolved Hello().

I tried using extern "C" , its not resolving symbol.

My aim is to link my grpc project(static lib) to KMDF. I get errors for unresolved external symbol for __imp_invalid_parameter and so on. Can someone help on which libraies or header files i need to include? I have tried including MSVC C++ include folder in additional header folders in project settings. And grpc related libraries which were needed to build helloworld project.